# How to Get a Stylus Pen Press Level Value - Autohotkey Script?

Tags: scripting, touch, autohotkey, gesture

**How to Get a Stylus Pen Press Level Value With An Autohotkey Script?**

I want to make a Script that can Monitor Continue A Stylus Pen Press Level Value on My Windows Desktop Computer.

Or if a Pressure Level Value Does have, for example a 70% pressure, that it then will do a Autohotkey Action. (execute a Part of Script) - Think About this If you use it then in combination with x,y Coordinate you can Make your own Advance Gestures Controls.

Maybe There is a Windows Registry Key that does have a Pressure Value.

[image: stylus pen pressure value][image: pen pressure]

I now that you can Get a Stylus Pen Click Value, (on/off) This is the same like [Left Mouse Click]

With this AHK Script.

```
;#notrayicon
#SingleInstance force

; + = Shift
; ! = Alt
; ^ = Ctrl
; # = Win (Windows logo key)

loop
{
sleep 50
GetKeyState, state, LButton
if state = D
{
MsgBox,, , The Stylus Pen is on the Touchscreen or [Left Mouse Button is Pressed], 2
} else {
;MsgBox,, , The Stylus is not on the Touchscreen, 5 
}
}

esc::exitapp
```